# Looking for the location of code behind Datagridview Edit Columns form

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview control on my form. I know that I can edit the columns on the form using the interface provided (see screenshot) however, my boss wants me to locate the code-behind this interface. I am not sure where to look or how to locate.

[image]

I hope that I am being clear here.

Comment: You should find it [here](https://i.imgur.com/PXHdgqV.png).

Comment: That is it! Tanks!